# Can't find reason for over allocation in iOS app (using Instruments)

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm using Instruments to check Allocations for my app.
The worst Category is "Malloc 5.00 KB" which gets to 20 and even 30 MBs.
When I get inside, I see that almost 100% of these allocations are from
the Foundation Library, 
something called "[NSConcreteMutableData initWithCapacity]"

I can't find the source for those allocations in my code or any detail about this function over the web...

Comment: It has to do with your NSData object, can you share code?

Comment: I like to use Product > Analyze in Xcode, it lets me know where the potential memory leaks are. If you haven't tried it, give it a shot.

Comment: thanks @JamesPaolantonio:
1. About NSData - I can't share code because there are many NSData objects in my code, where to start? It doesn't show that it's my libraries doing this allocation, but Foundation does...
2. Of course I used the Analyze - I got to the point I have almost zero leaks in my code. Actually the only two leaks left in my code are of nsdataformatter (a well known iOS leak problem) and of JSonParser (another well known leak), but those leaks don't cross the 300KB the most. Whereas if I check the "Allocations" I see up to 20MB allocations that I can't find the source...

Comment: @Zhang - I answered you too above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Found it!
After going over most of my code 5 times (!) without being able to find problems, I started to suspect 3rd party libraries.

The problem was in ASIHTTPRequest library. I used an old (mid-2011) version of that library. As soon as I replaced it with the newest version, most of the problem got solved.

Now I got to deal with the SBJsonParser and NSDataFormatter leaks, and I'm done :)

Thanks